# Automatically Crop HTML5 canvas to contents

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Let's say this is my canvas, with an evil-looking face drawn on it.  I want to use `toDataURL()` to export my evil face as a PNG; however, the whole canvas is rasterised, including the 'whitespace' between the evil face and canvas edges.

```
+---------------+
|               |
|               |
|     (.Y. )    |
|      /_       |
|     \____/    |
|               |
|               |
+---------------+
```

What is the best way to crop/trim/shrinkwrap my canvas to its contents, so my PNG is no larger than the face's 'bounding-box', like below?  The best way seems to be scaling the canvas, but supposing the contents are dynamic...?  I'm sure there should be a simple solution to this, but it's escaping me, with much Googling.

```
+------+
|(.Y. )|
| /_   |
|\____/|
+------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you want an auto-crop feature.  Hmm... I haven't worked with canvas too much yet.  Iterate through the horizontal lines to identify the bounds of your image where pixels are not white.  Then scan the vertical for the same.

Comment: @AlexW: I'm not entirely sure you understand what I'm after - I want cropping rather than scaling.

Comment: @CMKanode: Thanks for the comment.  That's pretty much been my thoughts for a last-resort kind of solution :P it's drilling it down to a fairly low level though, so I feel like there should be another way!

Comment: This should be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12178531/1066234

Answer (score 43):

**Edited** (see [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796554/automatically-crop-html5-canvas-to-contents#comment106458193_22267731))

```
function cropImageFromCanvas(ctx) {
  var canvas = ctx.canvas, 
    w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height,
    pix = {x:[], y:[]},
    imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height),
    x, y, index;
  
  for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
      index = (y * w + x) * 4;
      if (imageData.data[index+3] > 0) {
        pix.x.push(x);
        pix.y.push(y);
      } 
    }
  }
  pix.x.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
  pix.y.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
  var n = pix.x.length-1;
  
  w = 1 + pix.x[n] - pix.x[0];
  h = 1 + pix.y[n] - pix.y[0];
  var cut = ctx.getImageData(pix.x[0], pix.y[0], w, h);

  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;
  ctx.putImageData(cut, 0, 0);
        
  var image = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

Comment: This is awesome code for autocropping, thanks! I'll have to throw up a fiddle tomorrow as a payback ;)

Comment: The sort function is not necessary here. If you keep track of your minimum x,y and maximum x,y where pixel is not transparent, you can remove the sort completely.

Comment: The code works great, just need to put +1 in 

var cut = ctx.getImageData(pix.x[0], pix.y[0], w+1, h+1);

canvas.width = w+1;
canvas.height = h+1;

otherwise it cuts the last pixels.

Comment: This answer is a gem

Comment: Checking alpha channel (`imageData.data[index+3] > 0`) did not work for me since it was always greater than 0, had to switch to checking if the color is not white (it suits my needs since I have a white background): `imageData.data[index] != 255 && imageData.data[index+1] != 255 && imageData.data[index+2] != 255`. Then cropping worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: I am using fabricjs for generating customized shape images. It works good but I see lots of transparent background with an image.
So the image size is 1000px and the shaped area size is 100px then it shows 900px as transparent area and in 100px my custom shape. 
Can we remove that unwanted transparent area?

Comment: The parameter `canvas` is redundant since the `ctx` is also specified, it's simpler to get the canvas object with from [`ctx.canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/canvas).  Also, as mentioned, this was off by 1pc for both `h` and `w`, since, for example, if an image starts and ends on the same row, it has a height of 1, not 0. **I've corrected this in the answer.**

Comment: How could I adjust this so only the height is cropped?

Answer (score 11):

If I understood well you want to "trim" away all the surronding your image / drawing, and adjust the canvas to that size (like if you do a "trim" command in Photoshop).

Here is how I'll do it.

1. Run thru all the canvas pixels checking if their alpha component is > 0 (that means that something is drawn in that pixel). Alternativelly you could check for the r,g,b values, if your canvas background is fullfilled with a solid color, for instance.
2. Get te coordinates of the top most left pixel non-empty, and same for the bottom most right one. So you'll get the coordinates of an imaginay "rectangle" containing the  canvas area that is not empty.
3. Store that region of pixeldata.
4. Resize your canvas to its new dimensions (the ones of the region we got at step 2.)
5. Paste the saved region back to the canvas.

Et, voilá :)

Accesing pixeldata is quite slow depending on the size of your canvas (if its huge it can take a while). There are some optimizations around to work with raw canvas pixeldata (I think there is an article about this topic at MDN), I suggest you to google about it.

I prepared a small sketch in jsFiddle that you can use as starting point for your code.

[Working sample at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHyPX/1/)

Hope I've helped you.
c:.

Comment: Alternativelly to 3 - 5, you could use the solution of Alex W, translate the canvas and resize, probably will be faster than copy and paste the pixels :)

Answer (score 8):

Here's my take. I felt like all the other solutions were overly complicated. Though, after creating it, I now see it's the same solution as one other's, expect they just shared a fiddle and not a function.

```js
function trimCanvas(canvas){
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const topLeft = {
        x: canvas.width,
        y: canvas.height,
        update(x,y){
            this.x = Math.min(this.x,x);
            this.y = Math.min(this.y,y);
        }
    };

    const bottomRight = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        update(x,y){
            this.x = Math.max(this.x,x);
            this.y = Math.max(this.y,y);
        }
    };

    const imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    for(let x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++){
        for(let y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++){
            const alpha = imageData.data[((y * (canvas.width * 4)) + (x * 4)) + 3];
            if(alpha !== 0){
                topLeft.update(x,y);
                bottomRight.update(x,y);
            }
        }
    }

    const width = bottomRight.x - topLeft.x;
    const height = bottomRight.y - topLeft.y;

    const croppedCanvas = context.getImageData(topLeft.x,topLeft.y,width,height);
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    context.putImageData(croppedCanvas,0,0);

    return canvas;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's code in ES syntax, short, fast and concise:

```
/**
 * Trim a canvas.
 * 
 * @author Arjan Haverkamp (arjan at avoid dot org)
 * @param {canvas} canvas A canvas element to trim. This element will be trimmed (reference)
 * @param {int} threshold Alpha threshold. Allows for trimming semi-opaque pixels too. Range: 0 - 255
 * @returns {Object} Width and height of trimmed canvcas and left-top coordinate of trimmed area. Example: {width:400, height:300, x:65, y:104}
 */
const trimCanvas = (canvas, threshold = 0) => {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height,
        imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h),
        tlCorner = { x:w+1, y:h+1 },
        brCorner = { x:-1, y:-1 };

    for (let y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            if (imageData.data[((y * w + x) * 4) + 3] > threshold) {
                tlCorner.x = Math.min(x, tlCorner.x);
                tlCorner.y = Math.min(y, tlCorner.y);
                brCorner.x = Math.max(x, brCorner.x);
                brCorner.y = Math.max(y, brCorner.y);
            }
        }
    }

    const cut = ctx.getImageData(tlCorner.x, tlCorner.y, brCorner.x - tlCorner.x, brCorner.y - tlCorner.y);

    canvas.width = brCorner.x - tlCorner.x;
    canvas.height = brCorner.y - tlCorner.y;

    ctx.putImageData(cut, 0, 0);

    return {width:canvas.width, height:canvas.height, x:tlCorner.x, y:tlCorner.y};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The top voted answer here, as well as the implementations i found online trim one extra pixel which was very apparent when trying to trim text out of canvas. I wrote my own that worked better for me:

```js
var img = new Image;
img.onload = () => {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    autoCropCanvas(canvas, ctx);
    document.getElementById('button').remove();
  });

};
img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,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';


function autoCropCanvas(canvas, ctx) {
  var bounds = {
   left: 0,
   right: canvas.width,
   top: 0,
   bottom: canvas.height
  };
  var rows = [];
  var cols = [];
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
   cols[x] = cols[x] || false;
   for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
    rows[y] = rows[y] || false;
    const p = y * (canvas.width * 4) + x * 4;
    const [r, g, b, a] = [imageData.data[p], imageData.data[p + 1], imageData.data[p + 2], imageData.data[p + 3]];
    var isEmptyPixel = Math.max(r, g, b, a) === 0;
    if (!isEmptyPixel) {
     cols[x] = true;
     rows[y] = true;
    }
   }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   if (rows[i]) {
    bounds.top = i ? i - 1 : i;
    break;
   }
  }
  for (var i = rows.length; i--; ) {
   if (rows[i]) {
    bounds.bottom = i < canvas.height ? i + 1 : i;
    break;
   }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
   if (cols[i]) {
    bounds.left = i ? i - 1 : i;
    break;
   }
  }
  for (var i = cols.length; i--; ) {
   if (cols[i]) {
    bounds.right = i < canvas.width ? i + 1 : i;
    break;
   }
  }
  var newWidth = bounds.right - bounds.left;
  var newHeight = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;
  var cut = ctx.getImageData(bounds.left, bounds.top, newWidth, newHeight);
  canvas.width = newWidth;
  canvas.height = newHeight;
  ctx.putImageData(cut, 0, 0);
 }
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas style='border: 1px solid pink'></canvas>
<button id=button>crop canvas</button>
```