# Trim Image Whitespace Using CSS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, css

Has anyone experimented with removing the white (un-used) part of the image using CSS/JS? I have an image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXAHZ.jpg) that contains actual content surrounded by lots of whitespace that I want to remove using pure CSS if possible (perhaps `position:absolute; clip:rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);` or `background-size:cover;` or a combination), but unfortunately the location of the actual content in the image file is not known. The desired results is showing the wallet by itself.

I would much rather avoid a JS solution but if there's something that works and fairly performant, it will be awesome! It's possible to do in `PIL` ([Trim whitespace using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615901/trim-whitespace-using-pil)), but it would nice to avoid it if we have a frontend solution that works well 80%+ of the times.

[image: image with white space]

**Update:** what's the best way to smartly guess (or at least assume) the background position or clip location in a relative way (percentages)? Is it better to use a combination of `background-position`, `clip`, and `background-size` to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 3):

you can use background position, i made this for you

```
div {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/oA5ezhv.jpg') no-repeat;
  width: 230px;
  height: 160px;
  background-position: -35px -180px;
}
```

It makes an empty container of the size of the crop and then positions the background based on the position of the subject

[Here is the example working](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zAwBh)

If the image is dynamic and the whitespace proportions change then you will need to either use javascript or do it on the server side (gd or imagemagick in php)

Comment: Good edit about the dynamic size, I was just gonna point that out :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, upvoted! What are some ways to use JS for images of unknown whitespace proportion? I'm also wondering if it's possible to use CSS background-position w/ percentages instead of pixels? It would awesome to get a solutions that work well most of the time by relying only on the frontend.

Comment: yes, percentages are possible too, most units as far as i know, and for the javascript part check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175991/crop-image-white-space-automatically-using-jquery

Comment: As an aside, white space like that should be avoided as it does increase files size (and rendering time on a mobile device). However, I'm assuming it is unavoidable somehow in this case...