# cropping image white space on server side node

Tags: node.js, image-processing

I recently came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175991/crop-image-white-space-automatically-using-jquery) question. It's brilliant but unfortunately the code can't be implemented on the server side, and performance on client side is horrible.

How could I achieve this on the server side using node? It would be incredible if this could be done without downloading the images to the server, but I have no idea how that would work. Even if we downloaded the images to the server, I'm not sure how I would process them via node.

Comment: you cannot process an image server side if you don't download it to the server. you need to access data in order to process it...

Comment: @Piglet - that's what I had guessed. If image was downloaded, how would you process it to get rid of white space?

Comment: I don't know node.js so I can't help you. Just referred to your sentence "It would be incredible if this could be done without downloading the images to the server". But I assume you can use any image processing tool chain you want once you have the image on your server.