# Adding transparent space to PNG for 3d

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, three.js

I've got a problem where I have to resize images to the Power of 2 to load into Three.js. I've using the following to resize them:

```
            var w = powerOf2Down(this.width);
            var scale = w / this.width;
            var scaledHeight = this.height * scale;
            var h = powerOf2Up(scaledHeight);

            var scaleFactor  =  ( this.width / w) * ( this.height / h ) * 0.1;
            photo.scale.normalize().multiplyScalar(scaleFactor);


function powerOf2Down(value)
{
    if(value < 80) 
        return 64;
    else if(value < 150) 
        return 128;
    else if(value < 400) 
        return 256;
    else if(value < 800)
        return 512;

    return 1024;
}

 function powerOf2Up(value)
{
    if(value <= 64) 
        return 64;
    else if(value <= 128) 
        return 128;
    else if(value <= 256) 
        return 256;
    else if(value <= 512)
        return 512;

    return 1024;
}
```

This works in most places, but sometimes it scales up too much. I'm wondering adding white space to the smallest side rather than scaling might control is better.

Is it possible to do this in canvas and add transparent space to a PNG?

EDIT

Is this the right approach to scaling images to the power of 2 and retaining aspect ratio?

What I'm looking for I think is the opposite to this
[Automatically Crop HTML5 canvas to contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796554/automatically-crop-html5-canvas-to-contents)

Answer (score 0):

Going about this completely the wrong way. I didn't need to resize both aspects, only one will do