# Html5 Canvas and Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, html5-canvas

I currently have a webapp that allows the user to draw on the canvas and then the image is saved to my database.

My canvas size automatically resizes to the browser window which in some  cases is 1000px wide by 2000px high. So if just a small drawing is done in the middle of the canvas by the user, the saved image has a ton of white space around it.

Is there a way to automatically crop the images to just include the lines that are drawn or to just record the area of a canvas that is drawn on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796554/automatically-crop-html5-canvas-to-contents

Comment: Following the article you posted, where is the out modified file specified in that script. I see the code where you specifiy your source file but I do not follow the output. In other words, after the script crops the file, I do not see where it is outputted so that I can save that modified file to disk.

Comment: That was a client side alternative that I thought you might be able to harness to crop future-made/edited images. It was the first thing that came up in a google result. I also found this http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Cold_Fusion_Markup_Language/Q_24551879.html which may be right up your alley. Though the answer there is brief, a little bit of googling leads me on a breadcrumb trail that JMagick's `Trim()` could be what you're looking for.